# Изменение стиля строки ListView с сохранением разметки таблицы

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть ListView с GridView внутри:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListbox">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Mail" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Mail}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Всё работает хорошо:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, когда нам нужно изменить стиль строки, дабы добавить в некоторые из них слева специальный маркер, то создается стиль:

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Это стиль, с еще не реализованными маркерами, но он уже не работает (При добавлении к LW с помощью `ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}"`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить его так, что-бы он корректно отображал таблицу?

P.S. Возможно нужный результат добивается путем изменения другого стиля, или вообще другим способом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все оказалось достаточно просто, нужно в стиле заменить `ContentControl` на `GridViewRowPresenter`, и GridView станет отображаться.